# как обновить отдельное поле в таблице SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

есть 5 активити, на каждой активити производится ввод определенныз данных в таблицу. вопрос: как обновить отдельное поле в таблице:
если делать так :

```
myApplication.getOrder().setNAME("Петька");
```

то не обновится так как необходимо указать ID записи, а если делать так:

```
myApplication.setOrder(new Order(myApplication.getID(),null,null,"Петька",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null));
```

то сотрутся 1,2 поля, либо делать так :

```
 myApplication.setOrder(new Order(myApplication.getID(),"photo1","photo2","Петька",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null));
```

но тогда получается что каждый раз придется все поля перезаписывать..

создал класс Application и в нем создал экземпляр класса Order, при изменении мне приходится создавать новый экземпляр класса чтоб внести изменения, можно ли этого избежать?
 класс Update выглядит так:

```
 public int updateApplications(Order order) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(photo_1, order.PHOTO1());
        values.put(photo_2, order.PHOTO2());
        values.put(photo_3, order.PHOTO3());
        values.put(photo_4, order.PHOTO4());
        values.put(photo_5, order.PHOTO5());
        return db.update(list_applicationsTable, values, keyID + " =?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(order.get_id())});
    }
```

я так понимаю на вход Update надо подавать другое что-то, видимо строку? но если у меня, например, на 3 активити, 10 полей для ввода будет, то тогда как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно создать объект в первой активити, заполнить его в соотвествии с полями, которые представлены в данной активити, обновить это все в БД, если требуется конечно, затем передать этот объект в следующую активити

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Order", order);
startActivity(intent);
```

где Order

```
public class Order implements Serializable {
//ваши поля
}
```

и затем достать этот объект из другой активити. При нем уже будут поля, который вы заполняли в предыдущей. Делается это так

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Order order;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_scrolling);

    order = new Order();

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        //если приложение было убито ОС, то достаем сохраненное значение
        order = (Order) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("Order");
    } else if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
//иначе если запущенно с предыдущей активити, то достаем из extras
        order = (Order) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("Order");
    }

}


@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    //сохраняем сосстояние order, случай когда пользователь свернул приложение
    //и андроид убил его из-за нехватки ресурсов
    outState.putSerializable("Order", order);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
}
```

и так далее, пока не заполните все поля или что требуется по задачи.

Comment: Serializable имеплементить надо для фрагмента тоже